# Why is Lucifer portrayed with dirty feet?

Tags: constantine

At the end of the movie Constantine, we meet Lucifer: a man wearing an unstained white dress and dirty feet.

Why is he depicted like that? In particular: why the dirty feet?

Comment: Interesting question .... white suit hints at his past as an Angel, the dirty feet indicating some aspect of him being corrupted, earthly, no longer pure, or simply not flying as Angels are often depicted.  Not answering fully as I have not seen the movie and there may be context I am missing.

Comment: In addition to the symbolism, it may be visually attempting to invoke the image of hooves.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[According to Peter Stormare](https://www.avclub.com/peter-stormare-on-throwing-squirrels-and-why-michael-ba-1797991841):

> But I said, “My experience from stage is, if you do a devil or a really, really mean guy onstage, you usually come in like in Chekhov, off-white linens suit. My suggestion would be an off-white linen suit. **I should come from a bog, not from underneath, and I should have tar on my feet dripping down.** And then I can shave away my eyebrows, I can shave my head—you know, the sides of my head—looks weird, and the makeup artist added some veins on my face.” And I said, “If I’m dressed like that, everybody’s going to listen to me. They’re not going to be disturbed by, ‘He looks too fat. Wow. Fit? No, there’s a little belly. The tattoos are moving—they are cool.’ I could say whatever then. I could donate every single sentence to the starving people of Somalia. No one would hear.”

Note that I have not found any relevant Biblical texts to support this interpretation.

Comment: Also, [foot washing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maundy_(foot_washing)) has a certain religious significance.  Dirty feet, therefore, as imagery to contrast that.

Comment: I'm not sure the value of a TV Tropes link that basically repeats (with less info) the much more relevant quote that you've already found.